# LINQ to XML to with Multiple Namespaces in C#

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse the below XML in to the Entity through Linq, but i am not able to get the corresponding element.

```
<profile:learner type="" xmlns:profile="http://www.SumURL.com/XML/profile/2.0#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:vCard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#">
  <profile:personal type="">
<profile:id>123</profile:id>
<vCard:Name rdf:parseType="Resource" type="">
  <vCard:FirstName>ABC</vCard:FirstName>
  <vCard:LastName>XYZ</vCard:LastName>
  <vCard:UserName>XYZ ABC</vCard:UserName>
  <vCard:FullName>ABC XYZ</vCard:FullName>
</vCard:Name>
<vCard:Address rdf:parseType="Resource" type="">
  <vCard:Street />
  <vCard:Extadd />
  <vCard:Locality />
  <vCard:Region />
  <vCard:PinCode />
</vCard:Address>
<vCard:TelephoneNumber />
<vCard:EmailId />
<vCard:TimeZone>(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</vCard:TimeZone>
<vCard:Title />
<vCard:Organization rdf:parseType="Resource" type="">
  <vCard:OrgName>Q</vCard:OrgName>
</vCard:Organization>
<vCard:Role />
</profile:personal>
</profile:learner>
```

```
XNamespace env = xDoc.Root.Name.NamespaceName;
var a = (from level in xDoc.Descendants(env + "personal")
         select new 
         {
             PeopleID = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(level.Elements(env + "id").First().Value)) ? level.Elements(env + "id").First().Value : String.Empty,
             FirstName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(level.Elements(env + "Name").Elements(env + "FirstName").First().Value)) ? level.Elements(env + "Name").Elements(rdf + "FirstName").First().Value : String.Empty,
         }).ToList();
```

I am able to get the PersonID but not the FirstName, Lastname, Role etc.

Please tell me where i am doing wrong in the above Linq Query.

Please help me out.

Comment: What corresponding element? You haven't given us *nearly* enough information about what you're trying to do. All we know is that you've got some XML and you're having problems with it. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kjn pointed out, `Name` and `FirstName` elements are not in the `profile` namesapce, they are in `vCard`. And you have to reflect that in your code. You could also simplify your code a lot:

```
XNamespace profileNs = "http://www.SumURL.com/XML/profile/2.0#";
XNamespace vCardNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#";
var a = (from level in xDoc.Descendants(profileNs + "personal")
         select new
         {
             PeopleID = (string)level.Element(profileNs + "id"),
             FirstName = (string)level.Elements(vCardNs + "Name")
                                      .Elements(vCardNs + "FirstName")
                                      .FirstOrDefault()
         }).ToList();
```

Note that this will sometimes set the properties to `null`, instead of `string.Empty`, but I think that makes more sense if the data is not present.

Answer (score 1):

I think env + "Name" will resolve as "profile:Name" and not "vCard:Name" as you would probably want.

Comment: The above isn't particularly correct but the vCard namespace being wrong is the main reason for the code not working.